# How to hide Notification OneSignal in Unity3D

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, onesignal

I'm building an application that uses Firebase and OneSignal with client written in unity3d, the problem is that I want to receive notification but do not want it to display notifications when the app is not running. 
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding

This is the code from Firebase, everything runs fine

```
enter code here

var sendNotification = (data) => {
        var headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          "Authorization": "Basic YzA3MjYwZmMtNzUwYi00YWFiLThjNGUtYjYzMGM4NmM1ZWRl"
        };

        var options = {
          host: "onesignal.com",
          port: 443,
          path: "/api/v1/notifications",
          method: "POST",
          headers: headers
        };

        var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
          res.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log("Response:");
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
          });
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
          console.log("ERROR:");
          console.log(e);
        });

        req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        req.end();
    };

    var message = { 
        app_id: "752aef3b-5a0a-44be-8e94-f31d648cb866",
        contents: {"en": "English Message"},
        included_segments: ["All"]
    };

    sendNotification(message);
```

And I want to hide the notification when the app is not running,

[like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grCPN.png)

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the question